# The name of pointed sum of n-intervals

Tags: general-topology

this may be only a trivial question. But I wonder if there is any *known* name for the space $\bigvee^n I:=\bigsqcup^n [0,1]/\bigsqcup^n\{0\}$, namely n-folds pointed sum of interval. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called a [hedgehog space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedgehog_space), due to its spikiness which resembles a hedgehog (a little).

Comment: Thank you Daniel! This was what I wanted to know.